# How many observations ago value occured?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to Python, coming from a statistical background into the world of programming. I have recently been struggling with a thoughtfully quite simple task, though putting it into code seemed challenging.

Let's say we have a hand number (number of hands played), as one column, amount of winning in the second.

DATA.

```
g = pd.DataFrame({'HANDS':[0,1,2,3,4], 'WINNINGS':[1500,0,0,50,0]})
```

I would like to get an extra column, indicating how many hands ago happened the last victory.

DESIRED OUTPUT.

```
g['VICTORY_LAST'] = [0,1,2,3,1]
```

If I get it done and my poker project proves to be productive , I might share some pot. :D

Comment: What happens when the first winning is at index 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your arrays start becoming large, you might want to look into vectorizing the algorithm. Below is a vectorized solution, that depends on some numpy functions, which is the numerical library that pandas is built upon.

You are describing a sawtooth-like function: linearly increasing indices with resets at specific indices. Such a profile is the result from subtracting a staircase like profile from a linearly increasing profile. The staircase increases each time an event occurs to reach the same height as the linearly increasing line at that index. The code below does this:

```py
def count_ago(events, unknown_val=np.nan):
    """Count how many samples ago an event occurred.
    Example: events =  np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
             out= np.array([np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1])
    """

    dtype = np.min_scalar_type(unknown_val)  # space savings
    linear = np.arange(events.shape[0], dtype=dtype)
    staircase = np.maximum.accumulate((events != 0)*linear)
    sawtooth = linear - staircase
    first_event = np.nonzero(events)[0][0]
    sawtooth[:first_event] = unknown_val
    return sawtooth
```

The first few elements might be overridden with the `unknown_val` parameter if the event does not appear at the first index. That solves the problem of “when a game starts, how do you specify how long it's been since the last win?” The default value I've chosen is `np.nan`, as that makes sense for an undefined number.

Note that in your case, you're asking to keep increasing the implicit counter when an event occurs: at your winnings of 50, it was 3 steps since the last winning, not zero. That's easy enough: just shift all values by one index to the right, and increase them by one. That could be done with a function like `np.roll` but indexing works just fine:

```py
import numpy as np
# Uncomment this to extract the array from the pandas 
# dataframe as a numpy array (important for boolean indexing)
# wins = g.WINNINGS.values 

# Example array, slightly extended
wins = np.array([0, 1500, 0, 0, 50, 0, 20, 0, 0, 30, 2, 0, 0])
unknown_label = np.nan  # the label for indicating that you don't know how long ago an event occurred.
steps_ago = count_ago(wins, unknown_label)
adjusted = np.full_like(steps_ago, fill_value=unknown_label)
adjusted[1:] = steps_ago[:-1] + 1
# adjusted is: 
# np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1., 2., 3., 1., 1., 2.], dtype=float16)
```

Comment: Complicated at first, but solution more flexible and extendable. Nan-values obviously, more appropriate than zeroes in this problem. Thank you Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

This rather simple solution provides what you ask for. If anyone cares to improve it, i will be happy as well:

```
res = []
count = 0
for win in g['WINNINGS']:
    if win == 0:
        res.append(count)
        count+=1
    else:
        res.append(count)
        count = 1
g['VICTORY_LAST']= res
```

I think the code is rather self-explanatory. If you have questions, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty example:

```
wins = g.WINNINGS > 0

counter = 0
res = []
for win in wins:
    if win:
        if len(res)==0:
            res.append(counter)
            counter =0
        else:
            counter = counter+1
            res.append(counter)
            counter =0

    else:
        counter = counter +1
        res.append(counter)
g['VICTORY_LAST'] = res
```